# How to pop to previous screen and onWillPop is not called on persistent_bottom_nav_bar: ^5.0.2

Tags: flutter, dart

So, I am using this flutter library (https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) and I have been stuck for days now trying to figure out how to pop from Page B to Page A, after actually navigating from Page A to Page B. All I have tried so far has failed.

And also, the android back button doesn't call the `onWillPop` function, whenever the back button is tapped, it immediately sends the app to the background and that's not the behaviour I want.

My tabs are made like so:

```
 PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
    icon: const Icon(Icons.schedule),
    title: "Schedules",
    activeColorPrimary: Colours.darkyBlue,
    inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
  ),
```

and I navigate to a page within the tab, like so:

```
  PersistentNavBarNavigator
                            .pushNewScreenWithRouteSettings(
                          context,
                          settings: const RouteSettings(name: "/home"),
                          screen: AboutPage(),
                          pageTransitionAnimation:
                              PageTransitionAnimation.slideRight,
                        ),
```

I will appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have the answer, it's in the [library docs](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#some-useful-tips).
https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#some-useful-tips

Comment: So, how do I call `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName("/"));` from the back button?

Comment: Have you ever tried these settings on your PersistentTabView?
**`popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,`**
**`popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,`**

Comment: Yes, I have set these